# insert a values only in blank cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of specific names and one of the cell in a column is blank i want to copy a value from one selected cell and paste it in this blank cell.

```
Worksheets("project Allocation").Range("B8").Copy

Worksheets("Project Allocation").Range("****").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

I have copied value from cell B8 and want to paste values in the range of (R13: R200) cell which is blank. I am unable to define that paste range.

Comment: You can use the `SpecialCells` property of `Range` function to do this. I have answered below on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the  trick:

```
Worksheets("project Allocation").Range("B8").Copy

Worksheets("Project Allocation").Range("R13:R200").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

It will paste the value in `B8` to all the blank cells in the range `R13:R200`. In your case you only have one blank cell, so that will get the value.